# How to have a subtotal of calculated fields in InfoPath 2010

Tags: infopath

What I'm looking for is to total of a list of calculated fields. Have tried this with groups with no luck thus far.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Rob,
No. Unfortunately, it is a fixed table with calculations at the end of each row (fx). A repeating table did not seem appropriate at the time.

At the bottom of the column with all the calculated fields in it, I need to have a cell that totals all of those calculated fields (fx), like in Excel. Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way, but it seemed that the repeating table just added rows "as needed" rather than establish a pre-set amount of rows. Is this correct? Please advise. Thanks in advance for your assistance.

I have solved the problem, but I'm just thinking there has got be an easier way to do this.
-mba

Answer (score 0):

Is it a repeating table you are working with?  If so, I've used this before and it works: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/infopath-help/sum-a-column-of-numbers-in-a-repeating-table-HP010081939.aspx